# Задача по теории вероятности

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Условие задачи

> Сообщения `{x1,x2,x3,x4}` источника, заданного распределением
> вероятностей `{p1,p2,p3,p4}`, кодируются словами: `{00},{01},{10},{11}`
> соответственно.
>
> Необходимо найти вероятность появления единицы в
> первой позиции кодового слова при условии, что во второй позиции
> кодового слова появилась единица; вероятность появления сообщения `x2` при условии,
> что в первой позиции кодового слова появился нуль.
>
> Исходные данные:
>
> P1 = 0,2 + 0,005 * N;
>
> P2 = 0,3 - 0,005 * N;
>
> P3 = 0,1 + 0,01 * N;
>
> P4 = 0,4 - 0,01 * N;

Моя попытка решения

```
A – событие появления 0
B – событие появления 1

P({00}) = P(A)*P(A/A) = 0.2
P({01}) = P(A)*P(B/A) = 0.3
P({10}) = P(B)*P(A/B) = 0.1
P({11}) = P(B)*P(B/B) = 0.4

P(A) = P(A/A)/P({00}) = P(B/A)/P({01})
0.3*P(A/A) = 0.2*P(B/A)
P(B/A) = 1.5*P(A/A)
P(A/A)/P({00}) = 1.5*P(A/A)/P({01})
```

Попытка выше ни к чему не привела, т.к. в последнем выражении всё сокращается. Пожалуйста подскажите идею как решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трудно хорошо определить события "появление нуля" и "появление единицы". Вы можете определить события про цифры в определённой позиции: например "ноль в первой позиции". А без указания номера позиции ситуация усложняется. Но это и не нужно.

По определению условной вероятности:

```
P("единица в первой позиции" | "единица во второй позиции") = 
= P("единица в первой позиции" & "единица во второй позиции") / P("единица во второй позиции")
```

Из таблицы слов:

```
P("единица в первой позиции" & "единица во второй позиции") = p4
P("единица во второй позиции") = p2 + p4
```

Из таблицы значений вероятностей:

```
p4 / (p2 + p4) =
= (0.4 - 0.01 * N) / (0.3 - 0.005 * N + 0.4 - 0.01 * N) =
= (0.4 - 0.01 * N) / (0.7 - 0.015 * N)
```

Второй пример решается аналогично.

Comment: По здравом размышлении - хорошо, что вы опередили - это было бы чрезмерным усложнением, согласен.